# exists the mole that I didn't make

Tags: html, css, navigation, styles

I left a question because I saw a strange text(mole) while coding.

The above problem occurred while writing code for navigation menu and submenu.
If you look at the shop part of the navigation menu, there is a mole, and I would like you to help me look at what part of the code caused the mole.

And since the position of the rectangle of the submenu is skewed to the right, which part of the code should be modified to align the upper menu and middle as shown in the picture below?

[image]

thank you, in advance !

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = 3;
    $('.random').draggable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("z-index", a++);
      }
    });
    $('body div').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
      $(this).css("z-index", a++);

    });
  });
});

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".random");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
    const top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 30) + 1) + "px";
    const right = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 30) + 1) + "px";

    box.style.top = top;
    box.style.right = right;
  })
});

function showhide() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".random");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display =
        "block";
    }
  }
}

//draggable

function mouseDown(downEvent) {
  var box = downEvent.srcElement;
  var offX = box.getBoundingClientRect().left - downEvent.x;
  var offY = box.getBoundingClientRect().top - downEvent.y;
  document.onmousemove = e => {
    box.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(e.y + offY, 0), height) + "px";
    box.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(e.x + offX, 0), width) + "px";
  }
  document.onmouseup = e => {
    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
  }
  return false;
}

Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
  box.onmousedown = mouseDown;
})


//호버 혹은 클릭 시, div 컬러 변화

$(".music").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);

$(".music").click(function() {
  $('#result').load('album_list_index.php');
  $(".music").removeClass("active");
  $(this).removeClass("hover").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #edd6bc;
  border: none;
}

.random {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: move;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo nav" "logo notice";
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-area: logo;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-area: nav;
}

.notice {
  grid-area: notice;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

nav a {
  padding: 37px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: ;
  padding: 37px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav li>ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

nav li>ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav li>ul li a {
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: ;
}

nav li:hover>ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

main>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  background: #edd6bc
}

.hover {
  background: #edd6bc
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <header>

    <div class="logo" style="display: flex;">
      <img style="width: 70%; margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.imweb.me/upload/S202106158a019d8d01cb9/2b23eb2d2e178.jpg">
    </div>

    <nav>

      <a href="#" style="margin-left: -1px; border: 1px solid black;" class="music">About</a>

      <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid black;" class="music">Exibition</a>

      <li style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: -1px;" class="music">
        <a href="#">Shop</a>
        <ul>
          <li a href="#">리플랫</li>
          <li a href="#">작품</li>
          <li a href="#">MD</li>
        </ul>
      </li>


      <a></a>

      <a></a>

      <div style="display: flex; border: 1px solid black;">
        <button style="margin: auto;" onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></button></div>

      <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid black;" class="music">En</a>

    </nav>

    <div class="notice">( Current Exhibition | 2021.06.11-07.03 ) 젤다 킨
      <미끈한 반쪽> 전</div>

  </header>


  <div style="display: none; background: #6d97b4;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #c9656f;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #f1eb40;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #00825c;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #009ce0;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #cee4a6;" class="random"></div>



</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "mole"? As far as i know, a mole is a small animal that lives under the surface and digs in the earth.

Comment: I want to write dot (.) around text 'shop'. sorry for my translation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the dot from the shop link you could define `list-style: none` or you could omit the outer `<li>` which would be better, because there is no list arround it like `<ul>`:

```css
li.music {
  list-style: none;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = 3;
    $('.random').draggable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("z-index", a++);
      }
    });
    $('body div').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
      $(this).css("z-index", a++);

    });
  });
});

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".random");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
    const top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 30) + 1) + "px";
    const right = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 30) + 1) + "px";

    box.style.top = top;
    box.style.right = right;
  })
});

function showhide() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".random");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display =
        "block";
    }
  }
}

//draggable

function mouseDown(downEvent) {
  var box = downEvent.srcElement;
  var offX = box.getBoundingClientRect().left - downEvent.x;
  var offY = box.getBoundingClientRect().top - downEvent.y;
  document.onmousemove = e => {
    box.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(e.y + offY, 0), height) + "px";
    box.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(e.x + offX, 0), width) + "px";
  }
  document.onmouseup = e => {
    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
  }
  return false;
}

Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
  box.onmousedown = mouseDown;
})


//호버 혹은 클릭 시, div 컬러 변화

$(".music").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);

$(".music").click(function() {
  $('#result').load('album_list_index.php');
  $(".music").removeClass("active");
  $(this).removeClass("hover").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #edd6bc;
  border: none;
}

.random {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: move;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo nav" "logo notice";
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-area: logo;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-area: nav;
}

.notice {
  grid-area: notice;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

nav a {
  padding: 37px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: ;
  padding: 37px;
  text-align: center;
}

li.music, 
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav li>ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

nav li>ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav li>ul li a {
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: ;
}

nav li:hover>ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

main>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  background: #edd6bc
}

.hover {
  background: #edd6bc
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <header>

    <div class="logo" style="display: flex;">
      <img style="width: 70%; margin: auto;" src="https://cdn.imweb.me/upload/S202106158a019d8d01cb9/2b23eb2d2e178.jpg">
    </div>

    <nav>

      <a href="#" style="margin-left: -1px; border: 1px solid black;" class="music">About</a>

      <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid black;" class="music">Exibition</a>

      <li style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: -1px;" class="music">
        <a href="#">Shop</a>
        <ul>
          <li a href="#">리플랫</li>
          <li a href="#">작품</li>
          <li a href="#">MD</li>
        </ul>
      </li>


      <a></a>

      <a></a>

      <div style="display: flex; border: 1px solid black;">
        <button style="margin: auto;" onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></button></div>

      <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid black;" class="music">En</a>

    </nav>

    <div class="notice">( Current Exhibition | 2021.06.11-07.03 ) 젤다 킨
      <미끈한 반쪽> 전</div>

  </header>


  <div style="display: none; background: #6d97b4;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #c9656f;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #f1eb40;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #00825c;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #009ce0;" class="random"></div>

  <div style="display: none; background: #cee4a6;" class="random"></div>



</div>
```